# Haskell Recursion Subsets

Tags: haskell, recursion

i am new to Haskell. i am find it hard to understand  the below subset program  with recursion.what is the way it evaluates?

```
subset :: [a] -> [[a]]
subset [] = [[]]
subset (x:xs) = [zs | ys <- subset xs, zs <- [ys,(x:ys)]]
```

---

output: `[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]`

When i manually evaluate it is summing up as below

Manual Output:   `[],[3],[2],[1,2]`

I am missing some logic here can you please help me understand the above recursion concept and which part of guard statement will be evaluated first ,order of evaluation?

Comment: Just a tip: to format large code chunks, highlight it, and press ctrl+k. Only. Use "`" s for small pieces.

Comment: Please try to express how the last line constructs its result in English. I think that will make it clear how it works.

Comment: I can't help myself from pointing out this one-line gem that does what you want. It uses `filterM` from `Control.Monad`. `subset = filterM (const [False,True])`. And with just that, you get the same output (albeit arranged differently) as `subset` - it isn't even less efficient!

Comment: @Alec [`Data.List.subsequences`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences). Will also take only a single import.

Comment: @Zeta Oh of course. I have a fondness for that particular definition because IMO it brings out some of the best of Haskell - being able to define relatively complex operations succinctly in terms of highly polymorphic library functions. There is absolutely no boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line says that the set of subsets of `x:xs` is the set of subsets of `xs` along with `x` added to each of those sets.

Another way of putting it is that

```
zs <- [ys,(x:ys)]
```

generates exactly two sets, `ys` and `x:ys` for each `ys` which is one of the subsets of `xs`.