# Haskell Subset Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, subset

I am new to stack overflow and Haskell so please let me know if there is another way of doing this!

This is very much a repeat of this stack overflow question,[Haskell Recursion Subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058823/haskell-recursion-subsets), but the answer this question got didn't really help me and I'm still confused about how the recursion in this problem works. This is my attempt to get the conversation started again for this question.

Here is the question:

I am confused about how the recursion in the following code snip it works:

```
subsets :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsets [] = [[]]
subsets (x:xs) = [zs | ys <- subsets xs, zs <- [ys, (x:ys)]]
```

The output of this code is:

```
*Main> subsets [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

I understand how subsets is called recursively and how you can get to subset `[] = [[]]` but I am confused about how this returns a list of list and how it returns some list like `[1]`, `[1,3]`, and `[2,3]`.

Again, I'm new to stack overflow so please let me know if there is a better way of doing this besides repeating the question.

Comment: What's the smallest input you don't understand the workings of? Do you understand how `subsets [3]` works? Do you understand how `subsets [2,3]` works?

Comment: I get how `subsets [3]`  works but anything more than one integer in a list and I don't understand. Also how does `zs <- [ [ [] ], (3:[ [] ]) }` equivilate to `zs` being `[[],[3]]`

Comment: For clarification on what I'm asking above: I assume that `subset []` returns `[ [] ]` which is a list of an empty list, but the final output only shows it as a single list `[]`. Output: `[ [], [3] ]`

Comment: For completeness, the troll version: `subsets = filterM (return [True, False])`

Answer (score 5):

Let's first clarify `subsets [3]`. Remember that `ys <- [ [] ]` means `ys` takes on each of the elements in the list, `[ [] ]`, which just includes one element, `[]`.

```hs
   subsets (3:[])
=> [zs | ys <- subsets [] ...
=> [zs | ys <- [ [] ] ...
=> [zs | ys <- [ [] ], zs <- [[], (3:[])]]
= [[], [3]] -- zs takes on each element of [[], (3:[])]
```

Now let's ignore what is "actually" happening and put the logic into words.

```
subsets (x:xs) = [zs | ys <- subsets xs, zs <- [ys, (x:ys)]]
```

means:

```
Aggregate all zs
  where ys takes on in turn each of the subsets of the list without x,
  and for each ys,
    zs takes on the subset ys, and the subset ys and x together
```

For example:

```
   subsets [2,3]
=> ys takes on in turn each of the subsets of the list without 2
=> [[], [3]]

=> for each ys,
     zs takes on the subset ys, and the subset ys and 2 together
=> [[], [2], [3], [2,3]]
```

Comment: Thank You so much!!! I understand now how I was looking a the code wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@גלעד ברקן Supplement:
Suppose a set having **at least one** element is `{x,---}`. `x` means the first element, and `---` represents the rest elements.
`subset of {x,---}` is composed of `{x,---}` and `subset {---}`. In other words, the part that contains x and the piece that doesn't.

In terms of the list comprehension

```
subsets (x:xs) = [zs | ys <- subsets xs, zs <- [ys, (x:ys)]]
```

`zs` corresponding to `subset of {x,---}`
`zs <- [ys, (x:ys)]` means `zs` consists of two parts, which are `ys` and `(x:ys)`
`ys` corresponding to `subset {---}` Namely `ys <- subsets xs`
`(x:ys)` corresponding to `{x,---}`